# How to destruct object properties using filter or reduce of es6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Trying to delete the object properties using reduce method but its not returning expected response , what is correct method to use in below use case ? filter or reduce ?

main.js

```
const filtered = Object.keys(transformedResponse).reduce((res, key) => {

       delete res.drugName;
       delete res.mailPrice. copayEmployer
       delete res.retailPrice. copayEmployer
      return res;
    }, {});
```

transformedResponse

```
const transformedResponse = [
    {
        "isBrand": true,
        "drugName": "Lipitor",
        "drugStrength": "80 mg",
        "drugForm": "Tablet",
        "mailPrice": {
            "copayEmployer": 0,
            "prop2": "test"
        },
        "retialPrice": {
            "copayEmployer": 0,
            "prop2": "test"
        }

    }, {
        "isBrand": true,
        "drugName": "Metformin",
        "drugStrength": "500 mg",
        "drugForm": "Tablet",
        "mailPrice": {
            "copayEmployer": 50,
            "prop2": "test"
        },
        "retailPrice": {
            "copayEmployer": 0,
            "prop2": "test"
        }
    }

]
```

expected output

```
[
    {
        "isBrand": true,
        "drugStrength": "80 mg",
        "drugForm": "Tablet",
        "mailPrice": {
            "prop2": "test"
        },
        "retialPrice": {
            "prop2": "test"
        }

    }, {
        "isBrand": true,
        "drugStrength": "500 mg",
        "drugForm": "Tablet",
        "mailPrice": {
            "prop2": "test"
        },
        "retailPrice": {
            "prop2": "test"
        }
    }

]
```

Comment: Object.keys just returns an array of string, each string being a key of the object you passed in. You are then trying to reduce an array of strings. you cant do res.drugName because res is just a string

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to filter out the results

```
var x = transformedResponse.map((obj) => {
  return {
        "isBrand": obj.isBrand,
        "drugStrength": obj.drugStrength,
        "drugForm": obj.drugForm,
        "mailPrice": {
            "prop2": obj.mailPrice.prop2
        },
        "retailPrice": {
            "prop2": obj.retailPrice.prop2
        }
  }
});

console.log(x);
```

Map iterates over each item in the given array and returns a new array. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: mailPrice and retailPrice objects are big i just added one property just to showcase , i have to map each property in this approach right

Comment: Yes you pick what you want to return back in the new array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
const newTransResp = transformedResponse
    .map(
        a => {
            const {drugName, ...newA} = a;

            return {
                ... newA,
                mailPrice: {
                    prop2: a.mailPrice.prop2
                },
                retailPrice: {
                    prop2: a.retailPrice.prop2
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: there is another property at parent level drugName that should be removed from each object

Comment: `const newTransResp = transformedResponse.map(
    a => ({
        drugName ... a,
        mailPrice: {
            prop2: a.mailPrice.prop2
        },
        retailPrice: {
            prop2: a.retailPrice.prop2
        }
    })
)` can i do tthis

Comment: I just edited the answer omitting drugName, now it's fine

Comment: @hussain no, `.map` does *not* mutate the array. Not unless the callback you give it does but that's not the case here.

Comment: this is doing opposite it is keeping the properties that i want to remove

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```js
const transformedResponse = [
    {
        "isBrand": true,
        "drugName": "Lipitor",
        "drugStrength": "80 mg",
        "drugForm": "Tablet",
        "mailPrice": {
            "copayEmployer": 0,
            "prop2": "test"
        },
        "retailPrice": {
            "copayEmployer": 0,
            "prop2": "test"
        }

    }, {
        "isBrand": true,
        "drugName": "Metformin",
        "drugStrength": "500 mg",
        "drugForm": "Tablet",
        "mailPrice": {
            "copayEmployer": 50,
            "prop2": "test"
        },
        "retailPrice": {
            "copayEmployer": 0,
            "prop2": "test"
        }
    }

];

const resObj = transformedResponse.reduce((acc, curr) => {
 
        // Destructure the current object into its individual properties
 const { mailPrice, retailPrice, ...rest} = curr;

 const mailPriceObj = {};
 const retailPriceObj = {};
 
  // Extract the .prop2 property now
 ({ prop2: mailPriceObj.prop2 }  = mailPrice);
 ({ prop2: retailPriceObj.prop2 } = retailPrice);
   
        // Create the projected object now
 const obj = { ... rest };
 obj.mailPrice = {  prop2: mailPriceObj.prop2 };
 obj.retailPrice = { prop2: retailPriceObj.prop2 };

        // Push the projected object into the accumulator
 acc.push(obj);

 return acc;
}, []);

console.log(resObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the original list in-line, you can remove keys recursively using an object reference as such:

```
{
  "drugName" : true,
  "mailPrice" : {
    "copayEmployer" : true
  },
  "retialPrice" : {
    "copayEmployer" : true
  }
}
```

#### Example

**Note:** You have a typo in your first object i.e. `"retialPrice"` instead of `"retailPrice"`. This is why the `"copayEmployer"` field is not ignored in the copy.

```js
const data = getData()
const ignore = {
  "drugName": true,
  "mailPrice": {
    "copayEmployer": true
  },
  "retailPrice": {
    "copayEmployer": true
  }
}

console.log('Original:', data)
console.log('Cloned:', cloneAll(data, ignore)) // Does not alter data
console.log('Unmodified:', data)
console.log('Pruned:', pruneAll(data, ignore)) // Alters the data
console.log('Modified:', data)

// Main call to pass in the list to copy items
function cloneAll(data, ignoreObj) {
  return data.map(item => clone(item, ignoreObj))
}

// Clones an object and ignores properties
function clone(obj, ignoreObj) {
  if (obj === null || typeof(obj) !== 'object' || 'isActiveClone' in obj) {
    return obj
  }
  let temp = obj.constructor()
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (ignoreObj == null || ignoreObj[key] !== true) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
        obj['isActiveClone'] = null
        temp[key] = clone(obj[key], ignoreObj != null ? ignoreObj[key] : null)
        delete obj['isActiveClone']
      }
    }
  }
  return temp
}

// Main call to pass in the list to prune
function pruneAll(data, ignoreObj) {
  return data.map(item => prune(item, ignoreObj))
}

// Recursive helper method to work on each item
function prune(obj, ignoreObj) {
  if (obj != null && ignoreObj != null) {
    Object.keys(ignoreObj).forEach(key => {
      if (ignoreObj[key] === true) {
        delete obj[key] // Prune property-value
      } else {
        prune(obj[key], ignoreObj[key])
      }
    })
  }
  return obj
}

function getData() {
  return [{
    "isBrand": true,
    "drugName": "Lipitor",
    "drugStrength": "80 mg",
    "drugForm": "Tablet",
    "mailPrice": {
      "copayEmployer": 0,
      "prop2": "test"
    },
    "retialPrice": {
      "copayEmployer": 0,
      "prop2": "test"
    }
  }, {
    "isBrand": true,
    "drugName": "Metformin",
    "drugStrength": "500 mg",
    "drugForm": "Tablet",
    "mailPrice": {
      "copayEmployer": 50,
      "prop2": "test"
    },
    "retailPrice": {
      "copayEmployer": 0,
      "prop2": "test"
    }
  }]
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: not sure its not happening for me copied exact same code

Comment: @hussain Does it work in the snippet? It should. What browser are you running?

Comment: i am running chrome

Comment: @hussain Just tested it, works on mobile too. Make sure you did not leave anything out.

Comment: it should not mutate the original array but its doing it that is breaking test cases now

Comment: So you want a deep copy (without those properties)?

Comment: yes new array object should not have drugName,mailPrice.copayEmployer and retailPrice.copayEmployer

Comment: @hussain Added a clone solution and also kept in the prune logic.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @hussain first of all you have a typo in your data. I believe the property `retialPrice` in the first object should be `retailPrice` instead.
I don't have a way to use `reduce` but `map` works fine.
Here is my solution:

```
transformedResponse.map(obj => {
    return{
        isBrand:obj.isBrand,
        drugStrength: obj.drugStrength,
        drugForm: obj.drugForm,
        mailPrice: {
            prop2: obj.mailPrice.prop2
        },
        retailPrice: {
            prop2: obj.retailPrice.prop2
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const transformedResponse = [
{
    "isBrand": true,
    "drugName": "Lipitor",
    "drugStrength": "80 mg",
    "drugForm": "Tablet",
    "mailPrice": {
        "copayEmployer": 0,
        "prop2": "test"
    },
    "retailPrice": {
        "copayEmployer": 0,
        "prop2": "test"
    }

}, {
    "isBrand": true,
    "drugName": "Metformin",
    "drugStrength": "500 mg",
    "drugForm": "Tablet",
    "mailPrice": {
        "copayEmployer": 50,
        "prop2": "test"
    },
    "retailPrice": {
        "copayEmployer": 0,
        "prop2": "test"
    }
}
];

const transformed = transformedResponse.map(res => {
  const {drugName, mailPrice, retailPrice, ...result} = res;
  return {...result, mailPrice: {prop2: mailPrice.prop2}, retailPrice: {prop2: retailPrice.prop2}};
});

console.log(transformed);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const _cloneResponse = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(transformedResponse));
  const loggerResponse = _cloneResponse.map((data) => {
  const _response = pruneResponse(data);

    return _response;
  });

  logger().info('Drug Price Response=', { ...loggerResponse, memberId: memberId, pharmacyId: pharmacyId });

function pruneResponse (res){
  delete res.drugName;
  delete res.mailPrice.NDC11;
  delete res.retailPrice.NDC11;

  return res;
}
```